# How to create tsvector_update_trigger on Non-character type data

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sequelize.js

How can we create tsvector update trigger on Non-character data type.
For example,  i have created a ts vector trigger something like this.

CREATE TRIGGER tr_doc_id_col
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON document
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('tsv_doc_id', 'pg_catalog.english', doc_id');

Here,

tr_doc_id_col -- Name of the trigger

document -- Name of the table

tsv_doc_id -- tsvector form of the doc_id

doc_id -- Name of the column. It's data type is integer

This trigger should update the tsv_doc_id, when there is insert, delete or update happens on doc_id column.

But, the trigger is throwing an error saying that doc_id is not of character type (i.e it is not able to update based on non-character type column).
I have tried creating same kind of triggers on columns like title, body which are text data type. In this case it is working very well, but in the earlier case.
Can any of you tell me how to do in the case of non-character data type like doc_id?

Answer (score 0):

tsvector_update_trigger is just a convenience function, and it does what it does.  You can always write your own implementation of it with whatever embellishments you want (in this case, casting to text), but you can't change the behavior of the existing one.  But it is also rather obsolete.  The modern way to do it is with GENERATED columns.

```
create table document (
   doc_id int,
   tsv_doc_id tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('english',doc_id::text)) stored
);
```

Although I would question the utility of a tsvector which always contains exactly one integer.